# Создание api в AZURE для моб приложения XAMARIN

Tags: api, xamarin, rest, azure

Коллеги, доброго времени суток. Хочу разработать мобильное приложение, которое берет данные из облака AZURE, а именно хочу написать API, которую я бы по REST'у вызывал, и получал данные из БД. Но не могу конкретную литературу найти, в офф документации пока плохо ориентируюсь, в гугле конкретных примеров и уроков найти не удалось.
Подскажите, где можно получить такую базовую информацию, как создавать API в AZURE и как к ним обращаться, если кто то сможет приложить пример апи и запросом REST чтобы ее вызвать.

Язык программирования C#

П.С. мобильное приложение разрабатываю на Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-conference

Вот самое полное и работающее приложение на Xamarin.Forms с использованием Azure.